# Getting a 404 error whenever I fork a repo

Tags: github-api, git-fork, octokit-js

I'm trying to create a website that can fork a repo using Octokit, but I keep getting 404 errors.

```
const octokit = new Octokit({
    auth: accessToken
})
  
try {
    const response = await octokit.request('POST /repos/{owner}/{repo}/forks', {
        owner: 'google',
        repo: 'googletest'
    })
    console.log(response)
}
catch(e) {
    console.log(e)
}
```

RESPONSE:

```
POST https://api.github.com/repos/google/googletest/forks 404
HttpError: Not Found
```

NOTE:
The personal access token has repo permissions allowed.
The Github client ID and secret are valid.

I'm not sure what else to try.

Comment: with status code 404 there should be more info if yes can you share that?

Comment: I am getting a message that says - `HttpError: Not Found`

Comment: can you edit the question and add the full code in the end too? because it works on my end in nodejs